# Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nested, expression

I have to do simple remove "." from the strings before doing word count. It is working fine in two statements but giving me below error while writing in single statement. Am I doing something like stupid? Or it is a scope for improvement?

> > **Error:** org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions, but got: regexp_replace(explode(split(CAST(value AS STRING), \s+)), [.]*, );

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val testString = " I am X. X Works for Y."
val testDF = Seq (testString).toDF
val testDF1 = testDF.select(regexp_replace (explode (split($"value".cast("String"), "\\s+")), "[.]*", ""))
testDF1.show
```

Comment: explode function is a generator which generates new rows. So you can't use functions on explode

Comment: Got your solution. Thank you.

Comment: But documentation says : def
explode(e: Column): Column 
Creates a new row for each element in the given array or map column.

Comment: you can read my previous comment the first line

Comment: Thank you. Now clear. All the best.